# PHP url strings conflict "?" and "&"

Tags: php, string, url

I have a lang system in my website. When people click to switch to another language, the following will be added to the url: `?lang=`. The problem is, my website is divided by pages which add `?p=` to the url aswell. So basically, if they change the lang on one of those pages, it'll overwrite the `?p=` and go back to the main page. So it'll be `index.php?lang=`.

What is the code or how should I code it so that php verifies if there's already a `?` string in the url and switch `?lang=` to `&lang=`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`http_build_query`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) to avoid this problems:

```
$params = array(
    'p'    => 'foo',
    'lang' => 'bar'
);

echo http_build_query($params); // p=foo&lang=bar

echo '?' . http_build_query($params); // ?p=foo&lang=bar
```

Answer (score 1):

check if `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` is empty.

if yes, add `?lang=` otherwise add `&lang=`