# How can I make this work? http_build_query example

Tags: php, string, url, lang

How can I addapt the following `http_build_query` script for my webpage?

```
$params = array(
    'p'    => 'foo',
    'lang' => 'bar'
);

echo http_build_query($params); // p=foo&lang=bar

echo '?' . http_build_query($params); // ?p=foo&lang=bar
```

Related to [PHP url strings conflict "?" and "&"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12352625/php-url-strings-conflict-and)

Here's how my page works:

```
<a href="?lang=es">Español</a>
<a href="?lang=en">English</a>

<?php
    $p = $_GET['p'];
    $pages = array('g1', 'g2', 'g3');
    if (!empty($p)) {
        if(in_array($p,$pages)) {
            $p .= '.php';
            include($p);
        }
    }
    else {
        echo '<a href="?p=g1">Page 1</a> <a href="?p=g2">Page 2</a></li> <a href="?p=g3">Page 3</a>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: And what is the problem? You want to replace every statis href=".." with the http_build_query function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a function to merge query parameters with the current `$_GET` array.

```
<?php
function merge_queries(array $original, array $updates) {
    $params = array_merge($original, $updates);
    return '?'.http_build_query($params);
}
?>

<a href="<?php echo merge_queries($_GET, array('lang'=>'es')); ?>">Español</a>
<a href="<?php echo merge_queries($_GET, array('lang'=>'en')); ?>">English</a>

<?php
// code abbreviated for clarity
echo '<a href="'.merge_queries($_GET, array('p'=>'g1')).'">Page 1</a>
      <a href="'.merge_queries($_GET, array('p'=>'g2')).'">Page 2</a>
      <a href="'.merge_queries($_GET, array('p'=>'g3')).'">Page 3</a>';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do that very easy:

```
$urlpath = implode('&', $params);
$url = $yourhost . '?' . $urlpart;
```

Comment: How and where should I include that? I'm kinda new at this php thing.